# How to pass more than one function to the sympy.plot

Tags: python, sympy

This code works:

```
import sympy as sy
x = sy.symbols('x')
sy.plot(x, x**2, x**3, (x, -5, 5))
```

This also works:

```
fun=x
sy.plot(fun, (x, -5, 5))
```

This does not work:

```
fun=x, x**2, x**3
sy.plot(fun, (x, -5, 5))
```

How to pass more than one function to the plot arg?

Comment: See `show=False` in [sympy's plotting docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html). It's the very first example code on that page ([more direct link](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot.Plot.append)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just using sy.plot(*fun, (x, -5, -5)) will be fine. you should unpacking the

Comment: Sympy 1.7.1 creates in my environment an error message: `1486: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  cos_theta = dot_product / (vector_a_norm * vector_b_norm)` and an empty plot